# Android app stopped working for unclear reason

Tags: android

I've been coding this Android app (for Udacity android course) for some time and suddenly it stopped working. It should show a weather forecast for the week and display more data when a list item is clicked. I've managed to create the list, but everything crashed when creating the intents and activity for additional info.

Reverting the history didn't help. I tried to recreate the app from scratch, but it crashed at an earlier stage, before even showing the list items.

Can anyone make sense of this error? For me it seems, that something is wrong with my phone, because there are no references to my code.

Here's the error:

```
07-22 00:47:55.084  17339-17339/com.linasko.sunshine2 I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
07-22 00:47:55.124  17339-17339/com.linasko.sunshine2 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
07-22 00:47:55.194  17339-17355/com.linasko.sunshine2 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 228K, 2% free 17047K/17304K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
07-22 00:47:55.404  17339-17355/com.linasko.sunshine2 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 318K, 2% free 17241K/17588K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
07-22 00:47:55.434  17339-17339/com.linasko.sunshine2 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-22 00:47:55.434  17339-17339/com.linasko.sunshine2 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41652ba8)
07-22 00:47:55.444  17339-17339/com.linasko.sunshine2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.linasko.sunshine2, PID: 17339
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1349)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1608)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1983)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1740)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's the .java files of the code that worked previously.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

This is the second class. The getWeatherFromJSON function was given by the lecturers and probably has nothing to do with the error.

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    public ArrayAdapter mForecastAdapter;

    public ForecastFragment() {
    }

    final String POST_CODE = "Kaunas";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            new FetchWeatherTask().execute(POST_CODE);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        ArrayList<String> weather_strings = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"LOL"}));
        mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
               R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                weather_strings);

        new FetchWeatherTask().execute(POST_CODE);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

 /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the asynctask later,
 * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
 */
    private String getReadableDateString(long time){
        // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
        // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
        Date date = new Date(time * 1000);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d");
        return format.format(date).toString();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
     */
    private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
        // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
        long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
        long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

        String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
        return highLowStr;
    }

    /**
     * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
     * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
     *
     * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
     * into an Object hierarchy for us.
     */
    private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
            throws JSONException {

        // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
        final String OWM_LIST = "list";
        final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
        final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
        final String OWM_MAX = "max";
        final String OWM_MIN = "min";
        final String OWM_DATETIME = "dt";
        final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

        JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
        JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

        String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
        for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
            // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
            String day;
            String description;
            String highAndLow;

            // Get the JSON object representing the day
            JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

            // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
            // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
            // "this saturday".
            long dateTime = dayForecast.getLong(OWM_DATETIME);
            day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

            // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
            JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
            description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

            // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
            // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
            JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
            double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
            double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

            highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
            resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
        }

        return resultStrs;
    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;
            int numDays = 7;

            try {
                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are available at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                Uri.Builder uriBuilder = new Uri.Builder();
                uriBuilder.scheme("http").authority("api.openweathermap.org").appendPath("data")
                        .appendPath("2.5").appendPath("forecast").appendPath("daily")
                        .appendQueryParameter("q", params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter("mode", "json")
                        .appendQueryParameter("units", "metric")
                        .appendQueryParameter("cnt", "7");
                URL url = new URL(uriBuilder.build().toString());

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("ForecastFragment", "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally{
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e("ForecastFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] strs){
            if (strs != null){
                mForecastAdapter.clear();
                for (String day : strs) {
                    mForecastAdapter.add(day);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show your Activity layout?

Comment: I think the error is happening in `onCreateView` at `listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);` because `mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>...` is not correct. Double check that `R.id.list_item_forecast_textview` is actually in `R.layout.list_item_forecast`. I very well may be wrong, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something shady going on. Both the first app and the one I recreated from scratch started working perfectly when I tried launching them this morning.